# In a JavaScript event trigger, when is _this_ the same as e.target? order of firing?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Sample A:

```
<table><tr>
  <td onclick='return tdclick()'><img ... /></td>
</tr></table>
```

Assuming the user clicks on the IMG in the above, which is the following is true:

1. `tdclick` will fire twice, once for IMG and once for TD
2. will fire on IMG first, then TD
3. if and only if `tdclick` is firing on TD will `this == e.target`

Sample B:

```
<table><tr>
  <td onclick='return tdclick()'><img onclick='return imgclick()' ... /></td>
</tr></table>
```

Assuming the user clicks on the IMG in the above, which is the following is true:

1. the `imgclick` fires for IMG and `this == e.target`
2. then everything happens as in A above

C. lastly, if the event handlers were added via

```
td.addEventListener( 'click', tdclick, false );
img.addEventListener( 'click', imgclick, false );
```

would the same statements be true as before, or would statement A2 be reversed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample A:

1) False

2) False

3) False

The event will only fire once, because there is only one 'click' event attached to one DOM element.  Even if the event originated from a child element (such as the img), it doesn't actually fire until the event bubbling hits the parent.  In this circumstance, "this" will be the TD element (since it was the source of the event firing, and *it* called the function). But, if you look at the first argument passed by the event, and inspect it's data, you see that e.target is typically the IMG element.

```
var tdClick = function(e){
    console.log(e.target); // typically the IMG element
}
```

I say "typically", because some browsers call the originating element different in the event details object.  Some browsers it is 'target', some it is 'originalTarget', and there may be more.

Sample B:

1) Yes, imgClick fires for the image. Not sure what you mean by the 2nd part of your statement.  'this', when handling DOM events, is going to be the DOM element that fired the event. So, in this case, 'this' is the IMG element (which also happens to be e.target)

2) False, as previously stated :)

Sample C:

addEventListener does the same thing as manually adding the function calls in the 'onclick' attribute of your element.  So, behaviors are the same... with the caveat that I am actually not familiar with the third argument to addEventListener (per [Mozilla Dev Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener), it is named useCapture, and has to do with bubbling, I'm just not familiar with it)

I would recommend getting either FireFox with the Firebug extension, or Chrome and just testing some of these out.  Inside your event functions, just do console.log(this), or console.log(e), etc, and their development consoles will allow you to inspect all the gritty details of the object.  It's extremely useful. Just remember to take out your console.log() statements when you're done because they'll croak in IE.

Comment: thank you again!  I think I got confused because of how dragEnter works - which fires both on the IMG and the TD, so was assuming incorrectly this was standard behavior.  what you say makes perfect sense